# Take a string and use it as pure HTML?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

Lets say I have a string called Test, and its value is:

```
<img src=test.gif></img>

<p> Testing 123 </p>
```

Is it somehow possible to use it as code since the HTML isn't compiled?

Edit: I tried this and it didn't work.

```html
<body>
  <p id="myText" onload="HTMLThing()"> Soon. </p>
</body>

<script>
  var testString = "<img src=test.gif></img><p> Testing 123 </p>"
  function HTMLThing(){
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=testString;
 }  
</script>
```

Comment: Use it as code? In what language? HTML is markup, for displaying text.

Comment: Woops, clarified it in a title edit.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful? If so, please accept one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using, but certainly you can open a file(with .html extension) and dump the string to that file. Later, when you open the HTML file, you will get the rendered web page.

But be sure about the directory in which you create that file, should also contain the image, or you can change the image's location in the string.

Answer (score 0):

On your page you can create HTML element and give it some ID, e.g. "myText". E.g.:

```
<div id="myText">This is what's shown before Javascript runs.</div>
```

Then in your Javascript code you can do:

```
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML='<img src=test.gif></img><p> Testing 123 </p>';
```

That will fill your element with the above code with the obvious consequences (adding image and text) if that's what you want.

Update: If you're calling your Javascript function with the `onload` event, be sure to put `onload="myFunction()"` assignment into the `body` tag, since it doesn't work in `div`, `p` and so on. Alternatively, you can use `onClick` instead of `onload` which will work with `div`, `p` and other elements.

Comment: I tried but I must've done it wrong. I put it in an edit above.

Comment: @user2461795: You need to put `onload` into `body` - see an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. The problem was that the `<p>` element does not fire the `onload` event, but the `body` does.

```html
<body onload="HTMLThing()">
  <p id="myText">Soon.</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var testString = "<img src=test.gif></img><p> Testing 123 </p>";
    function HTMLThing(){
      document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = testString;
    }  
  </script>
</body>
```

There are several ways to do the `onload` event, another method:

```html
<body>
  <p id="myText">Soon.</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var testString = "<img src=test.gif></img><p> Testing 123 </p>";

    function HTMLThing(){
      document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = testString;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
      HTMLThing();
    }

  </script>
</body>
```